# How to match consecutive unicode with QRegExp?

Tags: regex, qt, qt4

I checked Qt's doc , it fully support matching of unicode with \xhhhh , but in that way i can only match known unicodes , how can i recognize a unicode string then ?

Thanks !

@update:

```
QString line;
if ( line.indexOf(QRegExp ("\\p{L}")) ) != -1 )
{
 /// blabla
}
```

It's not working , i didn't see the flow went inside the `if`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Don't know Qt regular expresions, but according to the [doc](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html)

> QRegExp is modeled on Perl's regexp language. It fully supports Unicode.

I would assume that it should then support Unicode Properties, Scripts and Blocks. For a detailed overview see [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

You could e.g. use the property letter `\p{L}` to match a unicode codepoint with the property letter. To match a string consisting only of such code points use something like this

```
^\p{L}+$
```

Comment: If your string has a letter in it, your expression should match (I assume QRegExp allows this syntax). I have no idea if your syntax to match the regex against the string is correct and what the content of your line is. Test it with a string that has no exotic letter, but a "normal" letter in it and see if it matches this.

Comment: QRegExp r("^\\p{L}+$");
    QString a("aaa");
    qDebug() << "isValid:" << r.isValid() << "indexIn:" << r.indexIn(a); //doesn't work isValid returns false. So that shouldn't be the accepted answer,

Comment: For Qt5 users coming across this question, `QRegularExpression{"^\\p{L}+$"}` works